# Unsmooth sliding-up animation

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation, css-animations

I have created [this page](https://dylananderton.github.io/profile/) and when the "got it" button on the top panel is clicked, the panel will slide up and disappear while the page will also move up to cover the panel space. I have noticed that when the animation plays, it is not that smooth as white space can be seen in the split second that the page is sliding up. Is there any way to improve the animation to remove the split second in which the white space can be seen?

The code below is only a part of the complete one and won't be working properly like [this one here](https://dylananderton.github.io/profile/) as it is for reference only. Only pure HTML, CSS and Javascript are used.

```js
const panel = document.getElementById("panel");
const page = document.getElementById("main-page");

function closePanel() {
  panel.classList.add("panel-animation");
  page.classList.add("page-animation");
  setTimeout((panel.style.transform = "translateY(-1000px)"), 1000);
  setTimeout((page.style.top = "0"), 1000);
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.panel {
  height: 10%;
  width: 100%;
}

.notif-panel {
  z-index: 1;
  position: fixed;
  display: grid;
  height: 10%;
  width: 100%;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr;
  grid-template-areas: "panel-content";
}

.panel-content {
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: var(--smokeGrey);
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.panel-text {
  display: inline;
}

.cookie,
.privacy,
.tos {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.panel-button {
  display: inline;
  margin-left: 40px;
  padding: 10px 16px;
  background-color: #007bc1;
  color: white;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 2px;
}

.panel-button:hover {
  background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) 0 0);
}

@media (max-width: 675px) {
  .notif-panel {
    height: 10%;
  }
  .panel-content {
    padding: 0 5px;
  }
  .panel-text {
    padding-right: 15px;
  }
  .panel-button {
    font-size: 17px;
    margin: 0;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 605px) {
  .notif-panel {
    height: 15%;
  }
  .panel-content {
    align-items: left;
    display: block;
    padding: 10px;
    font-size: 18px;
  }
  .panel-text {
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    display: block;
  }
  .panel-button {
    font-size: 17px;
    margin: 0;
  }
}

.main-page {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
}

.hero {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-image: linear-gradient(
      rgba(0, 74, 117, 0.52),
      rgba(0, 74, 117, 0.52)
    ),
    url("assets/work-desk__dustin-lee.jpg");
  height: 600px;
}

.logo {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 30px;
  top: 25px;
}

.hero-content {
  margin: 0;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
}

.name {
  font-size: 30px;
}

.contact-text {
  margin-top: 8px;
  padding-bottom: 25px;
}

.contact-button {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: white;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: white 2px solid;
  padding: 12px 15px;
  border-radius: 2px;
}

.contact-button:hover {
  color: var(--blue);
  background-color: white;
}

.panel-animation {
  animation: animation1 1s ease-in-out;
}

.page-animation {
  animation: animation2 0.2s ease-in-out;
}

@keyframes animation1 {
  from {
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
  to {
    transform: translateY(-500px);
  }
}

@keyframes animation2 {
  0% {
    top: 10%;
  }
  100% {
    top: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="panel" id="panel">
  <div class="notif-panel" id="notifPanel">
    <div class="panel-content">
      <p class="panel-text">
        By accessing and using this website, you acknowledge that you have read
        and <span class="brCust" id="brCust"></span>understand our
        <a class="cookie" href="#">Cookie Policy</a>,
        <a class="privacy" href="#">Privacy Policy</a>, and our
        <a class="tos" href="#">Terms of Service</a>.
      </p>
      <button class="panel-button" onclick="closePanel()">Got it</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="main-page" id="main-page">
  <section class="hero" id="hero">
    <img src="assets/y-logo-white.png" class="logo" />
    <div class="hero-content">
      <p class="name">Hello! I'm Dylan Anderton</p>
      <h2 class="slogan">Consult, Design, and Develop Websites</h2>
      <p class="contact-text">
        Have something great in mind? Feel free to contact me.<br />
        I'll help you to make it happen.
      </p>
      <button class="contact-button">LET'S MAKE CONTACT</button>
    </div>
  </section>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## The problem

Your `#panel` is a sibling of `main`, but you want `#panel` to be fixed on the upper side of the viewport even when scrolling: You solved that with `position: fixed`.

But using `position: fixed` means that `#panel` will only be perfectly layed out on certain screen sizes. On any other screen size, and it may overlap `main`'s content. Also, it may cause visual jitter when animating (see section "Using `position: sticky`").

You also want `#panel` to slide out when requested, and `main` to take up the then-empty space: You solved that slide-out and "slide into place" with 2 different animations; `#panel` moves out by a lot, but `main` moves only enough to take up the empty space. Additionally, they move for a different duration.

The different distances and durations of the animations cause them to be not in sync with each other. Ideally both should move by the same amount and in the same time to make it look smooth.

Overexaggerated example of the issue:

```css
section:hover #banner {
  top: -400px;
  transition-duration: 1s;
}
section:hover #content {
  top: -80px;
  transition-duration: 2s;
}

/* PRESENTATIONAL STYLING */
body {font-family:sans-serif}
section {
  width: fit-content;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
}

#viewport {
  border: 1px solid black;
  grid-row: 1/1;
  grid-column: 1/-1;
}
#page {
  grid-row: 1/1;
  grid-column: 2/2;
}

#banner, #content {
z-index: -1;
  --size: 80px;
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  width: var(--size);
  height: var(--size);
  color: white;
  transition-property: top;
}
#banner {background-color:firebrick}
#content {background-color:darkblue}
```

```html
<section>
  <div id="viewport">Viewport</div>
  <div id="page">
    <div id="banner">Banner</div>
    <div id="content">Content</div>
  </div>
</section>
```

## Solutions

### Using `position: sticky`

Using `position: sticky` on `#panel` means that when scrolled, `#panel` will be on top of `main`'s content, as with `position: fixed`. But unlike `fixed`, `sticky` will still place the element in the flow, which means it will not overlap `main` when not scrolled. No magic numbers or JS needed for this!

And when wanting to hide `#panel`, we can shrink it and slide it out of the viewport, so that `main` can take up the empty space:

```js
const panel = document.getElementById('panel');
const page = document.getElementById('main-page');

function closePanel(){
  const {bottom} = panel.getBoundingClientRect();
  panel.style.marginBottom = 0 + "px";
  panel.addEventListener("transitionend", () => panel.replaceWith());
  
  // marginBottom shrinks the element;
  // translateY() slides it out.
  
  setTimeout(() => {
    panel.style.marginBottom = `${-bottom}px`;
    panel.style.transform = `translateY(${-bottom}px)`;
  }, 0);
}
```

```css
.panel{
  z-index: 1;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  transition:
    margin-bottom 1s,
    transform 1s;
}
.hero {
  position: relative;
}

*{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
html {--smokeGrey:#eee}

.notif-panel{
  display:grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr;
  grid-template-areas: "panel-content";
}

.panel-content{
  display:flex;
  justify-content:center;
  align-items:center;
  background-color:var(--smokeGrey);
}

.panel-text{
  display:inline;
}

.cookie, .privacy, .tos{
  text-decoration:none;
}

.panel-button{
  display:inline;
  padding: 10px 16px;
  background-color: #007bc1;
  color: white;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 2px;
}

.panel-button:hover{
  background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) 0 0);
}

@media(max-width:675px){
  .notif-panel{
    height: 10%;
  }
  .panel-content{
    padding: 0 5px;
  }
  .panel-text{
    padding-right: 15px;
  }
  .panel-button{
    font-size: 17px;
}
}

@media(max-width:605px){
  .notif-panel{
    height: 15%;
  }
  .panel-content{
    align-items: left;
    display: block;
    padding: 10px;
    font-size: 18px;
  }
  .panel-text{
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    display: block;
  }
  .panel-button{
    font-size: 17px;
}
}

.main-page{
  width: 100%;
}

.hero{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0,74,117,.52),rgba(0,74,117,.52)), url('assets/work-desk__dustin-lee.jpg');
  height: 600px;
}

.logo{
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 30px;
  top: 25px;
}

.hero-content{
  margin:0;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
}

.name{
  font-size: 30px;
}

.contact-text{
  margin-top: 8px;
  padding-bottom: 25px;
}

.contact-button{
  font-weight: bold;
  color: white;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: white 2px solid;
  padding: 12px 15px;
  border-radius: 2px;
}

.contact-button:hover{
  color: var(--blue);
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="panel" id="panel">
  <div class="notif-panel" id="notifPanel">
    <div class="panel-content">
      <p class="panel-text">By accessing and using this website, you acknowledge that you have read and
        <span class="brCust" id="brCust"></span>understand our
        <a class="cookie" href="#">Cookie Policy</a>,
        <a class="privacy" href="#">Privacy Policy</a>, and our
        <a class="tos" href="#">Terms of Service</a>.
      </p>
      <button class="panel-button" onclick="closePanel()">Got it</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="main-page" id="main-page">
  <section class="hero" id="hero">
      <img src="assets/y-logo-white.png" class="logo">
      <div class="hero-content">
          <p class="name">Hello! I'm Dylan Anderton</p>
          <h2 class="slogan">Consult, Design, and Develop Websites</h2>
          <p class="contact-text">Have something great in mind? Feel free to contact me.<br> I'll help you to make it happen.</p>
          <button class="contact-button">LET'S MAKE CONTACT</button>
      </div>
  </section>
</div>
```

Did you notice that when scrolled and hiding `#panel`, `main` won't jitter? Using `position: sticky` is the least visually jarring, which makes it **my preferred method to use**. Compare with the visual jitter of the other examples, or even your own webpage on smaller screen sizes!

### Using transitions

To move both elements (`#panel` and `main`) by the same amount, we have to find the y-position of `#panel`. This can be done with [`Element.getBoundingClientRect()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect).

Then, we want to move both elements upwards:

1. Move bottom of `#panel` from found y-position to 0.
2. Move top of `main` from found y-position to 0.

This can be done as follows:

```js
const panel = document.getElementById('panel');
const page = document.getElementById('main-page');

function closePanel(){
  const rectPanel = panel.getBoundingClientRect();
  panel.style.top = 0;
  page.style.top = rectPanel.bottom + "px";
  
  panel.style.transition = "top 1s ease-in-out";
  page.style.transition = "top 1s ease-in-out";
  
  // Don't forget to remove it from the DOM
  panel.addEventListener("transitionend", () => panel.replaceWith());
  
  setTimeout(() => {
    panel.style.top = -rectPanel.bottom + "px";
    page.style.top = 0;
  }, 0);
}
```

```css
/* I had to move position:fixed to this top-level element */
.panel{
  z-index: 1;
  position: fixed;
}

*{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
html {--smokeGrey:#eee}

.notif-panel{
  display:grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr;
  grid-template-areas: "panel-content";
}

.panel-content{
  display:flex;
  justify-content:center;
  align-items:center;
  background-color:var(--smokeGrey);
}

.panel-text{
  display:inline;
}

.cookie, .privacy, .tos{
  text-decoration:none;
}

.panel-button{
  display:inline;
  padding: 10px 16px;
  background-color: #007bc1;
  color: white;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 2px;
}

.panel-button:hover{
  background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) 0 0);
}

@media(max-width:675px){
  .notif-panel{
    height: 10%;
  }
  .panel-content{
    padding: 0 5px;
  }
  .panel-text{
    padding-right: 15px;
  }
  .panel-button{
    font-size: 17px;
}
}

@media(max-width:605px){
  .notif-panel{
    height: 15%;
  }
  .panel-content{
    align-items: left;
    display: block;
    padding: 10px;
    font-size: 18px;
  }
  .panel-text{
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    display: block;
  }
  .panel-button{
    font-size: 17px;
}
}

.main-page{
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
}

.hero{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0,74,117,.52),rgba(0,74,117,.52)), url('assets/work-desk__dustin-lee.jpg');
  height: 600px;
}

.logo{
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 30px;
  top: 25px;
}

.hero-content{
  margin:0;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
}

.name{
  font-size: 30px;
}

.contact-text{
  margin-top: 8px;
  padding-bottom: 25px;
}

.contact-button{
  font-weight: bold;
  color: white;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: white 2px solid;
  padding: 12px 15px;
  border-radius: 2px;
}

.contact-button:hover{
  color: var(--blue);
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="panel" id="panel">
  <div class="notif-panel" id="notifPanel">
    <div class="panel-content">
      <p class="panel-text">By accessing and using this website, you acknowledge that you have read and
        <span class="brCust" id="brCust"></span>understand our
        <a class="cookie" href="#">Cookie Policy</a>,
        <a class="privacy" href="#">Privacy Policy</a>, and our
        <a class="tos" href="#">Terms of Service</a>.
      </p>
      <button class="panel-button" onclick="closePanel()">Got it</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="main-page" id="main-page">
  <section class="hero" id="hero">
      <img src="assets/y-logo-white.png" class="logo">
      <div class="hero-content">
          <p class="name">Hello! I'm Dylan Anderton</p>
          <h2 class="slogan">Consult, Design, and Develop Websites</h2>
          <p class="contact-text">Have something great in mind? Feel free to contact me.<br> I'll help you to make it happen.</p>
          <button class="contact-button">LET'S MAKE CONTACT</button>
      </div>
  </section>
</div>
```

### Using Web Animations API

Same steps as when *using transitions*, but implemented via the [Web Animations API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Animations_API/Using_the_Web_Animations_API):

```js
const panel = document.getElementById('panel');
const page = document.getElementById('main-page');

function closePanel(){
  const {bottom} = panel.getBoundingClientRect();
  const duration = 1000; // ms
  
  panel.animate(
      { top: [0, `${-bottom}px`] },
    { duration }
  ).finished.then(() => {
    panel.replaceWith(); // Don't forget to remove element from DOM!
  });
  
  page.animate(
    { top: [`${bottom}px`, 0] },
    { duration }
  );
}
```

```css
/* I had to move position:fixed to this top-level element */
.panel{
  z-index: 1;
  position: fixed;
}

*{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
html {--smokeGrey:#eee}

.notif-panel{
  display:grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr;
  grid-template-areas: "panel-content";
}

.panel-content{
  display:flex;
  justify-content:center;
  align-items:center;
  background-color:var(--smokeGrey);
}

.panel-text{
  display:inline;
}

.cookie, .privacy, .tos{
  text-decoration:none;
}

.panel-button{
  display:inline;
  padding: 10px 16px;
  background-color: #007bc1;
  color: white;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 2px;
}

.panel-button:hover{
  background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) 0 0);
}

@media(max-width:675px){
  .notif-panel{
    height: 10%;
  }
  .panel-content{
    padding: 0 5px;
  }
  .panel-text{
    padding-right: 15px;
  }
  .panel-button{
    font-size: 17px;
}
}

@media(max-width:605px){
  .notif-panel{
    height: 15%;
  }
  .panel-content{
    align-items: left;
    display: block;
    padding: 10px;
    font-size: 18px;
  }
  .panel-text{
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    display: block;
  }
  .panel-button{
    font-size: 17px;
}
}

.main-page{
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
}

.hero{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0,74,117,.52),rgba(0,74,117,.52)), url('assets/work-desk__dustin-lee.jpg');
  height: 600px;
}

.logo{
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 30px;
  top: 25px;
}

.hero-content{
  margin:0;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
}

.name{
  font-size: 30px;
}

.contact-text{
  margin-top: 8px;
  padding-bottom: 25px;
}

.contact-button{
  font-weight: bold;
  color: white;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: white 2px solid;
  padding: 12px 15px;
  border-radius: 2px;
}

.contact-button:hover{
  color: var(--blue);
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="panel" id="panel">
  <div class="notif-panel" id="notifPanel">
    <div class="panel-content">
      <p class="panel-text">By accessing and using this website, you acknowledge that you have read and
        <span class="brCust" id="brCust"></span>understand our
        <a class="cookie" href="#">Cookie Policy</a>,
        <a class="privacy" href="#">Privacy Policy</a>, and our
        <a class="tos" href="#">Terms of Service</a>.
      </p>
      <button class="panel-button" onclick="closePanel()">Got it</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="main-page" id="main-page">
  <section class="hero" id="hero">
      <img src="assets/y-logo-white.png" class="logo">
      <div class="hero-content">
          <p class="name">Hello! I'm Dylan Anderton</p>
          <h2 class="slogan">Consult, Design, and Develop Websites</h2>
          <p class="contact-text">Have something great in mind? Feel free to contact me.<br> I'll help you to make it happen.</p>
          <button class="contact-button">LET'S MAKE CONTACT</button>
      </div>
  </section>
</div>
```

Notice that I used a [keyframe format](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Animations_API/Keyframe_Formats#syntax) where I specify the values of a property in steps.

Comment: I really like all of your solutions and I like the `sticky` one the most but weirdly I have found that for the `.panel` to have `height:10%;` and `.panel-content` to have `display: flex`, it cannot move past further the `class="hero"`, hence rendering it useless on mobile screen. For it to move past further `class="hero"`, `body` 's height must be set to auto and `.panel` 's height will then disappear, leaving it with no padding surrounding the content. The latter 2 actually causes the logo, which is the broken picture in the snippet to move down first then up upon button click.

Comment: Turns out I just have to not set anything to `body`'s height. I can just set `.panel`'s height to vh instead of body's height and everything is working according to what I want now. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your function like this:

```
function closePanel(){  
  setTimeout(() => {
    panel.classList.add('panel-animation');
  },1000);
  setTimeout(() => {
     page.classList.add('page-animation');
  },1000);
}
```

and implement the bottom two styles in your css i.e in .panel-animation and .page-animation respectively.

```
panel.style.transform = "translateY(-1000px)"
page.style.top = "0"
```

Comment: Thankyou for your input. Unfortunately, this doesn't solve the problem, putting the `classList.add` inside the `setTimeout` causes a 1s delay after pushing the button. The white space can also still be seen during the animation. More suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: OK may be don't use the setTimeout  to add the class list if you don't want the 1s gap and just add the classes in the close panel function as before and use fixed positioning in your css as suggested in the answers above. And i also don't think you need animation for this purpose just use the transform: translateY() and transition in your css. obviously you need to play around to get the desired output. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Trying to synchronise the animation of the panel and main elements is proving a problem.

Also, you want the top part of the main element to be visible, however much space the panel requires. Setting the height of panel to 10% will not work on all viewports - it will be too big on some and too small on others - and it may overwrite the top of main's content.

So, scrap the fixed on panel, scrap the animations and instead find out what height the panel is actually taking up, set it's height explicitly to that and then when the user clicks got it shrink the panel to 0px.

If you set a transition on panel this will be a smooth shrinkage.

This snippet takes your basic HTML and demonstrates this. It sets the transition time to 2seconds so you can see the shrinkage is smooth.

```js
const panel = document.getElementById('panel');
panel.style.height = panel.getBoundingClientRect().height + 'px';

function closePanel() {
  panel.style.height = "0px";
}
```

```css
#panel {
  transition: height 2s linear;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="panel" id="panel">
  <div class="notif-panel" id="notifPanel">
    <div class="panel-content">
      <p class="panel-text">By accessing and using this website, you acknowledge that you have read and
        <span class="brCust" id="brCust"></span>understand our
        <a class="cookie" href="#">Cookie Policy</a>,
        <a class="privacy" href="#">Privacy Policy</a>, and our
        <a class="tos" href="#">Terms of Service</a>.
      </p>
      <button class="panel-button" onclick="closePanel()">Got it</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="main-page" id="main-page">
  <section class="hero" id="hero">
    <img src="assets/y-logo-white.png" class="logo">
    <div class="hero-content">
      <p class="name">Hello! I'm Dylan Anderton</p>
      <h2 class="slogan">Consult, Design, and Develop Websites</h2>
      <p class="contact-text">Have something great in mind? Feel free to contact me.<br> I'll help you to make it happen.</p>
      <button class="contact-button">LET'S MAKE CONTACT</button>
    </div>
  </section>
</div>
```